# Why Firefox 33 shows "is not fully secured" on the first load?

Tags: apache, firefox, https

I am trying to setup my HTTPs website with Apache 2.2 and Firefox 33.
On the first load Firefox shows that warning.

[image: The connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains unencrypted elemets (such as images).]

But on the next page load (i.e. F5, another tab, etc until firefox restarts) everything on this URL is secure.

The page is just plain HTML, no javascripts, no images. I put robots.txt and favicon.ico into the /var/www/site/htdocs/ (I thought firefox loads them from http:// instead of https://). But this did not helped.

So, why firefox shows this warning on the first view after launch and don't does that later?

(I tried to ask this question on server fault, but don't have enough reputation to upload pictures)

UPD: Tools -> Web Development -> WebConsole says

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor/26570853?rn=493111185&page-url=http%3A%2F%2Fstart.calculate-linux.ru%2F&wmode=0&wv-type=0&wv-hit=372504783&wv-part=1&wv-check=34794&browser-info=z%3A240%3Ai%3A20141022210348%3Arqnl%3A1%3Ast%3A1413997437. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. 26570853

Everything becomes ok, when I set about:blank as homepage.

But the question remains - how (in this scenario) scripts from previous page can affect next page?

Comment: First check if your Firefox AddOns are creating the issue by starting firefox in `safemode` (A temporary mode, in which all Extensions are disabled). If the issue goes away when running in this mode, you can be sure that one of your extensions are creating this issue.

Comment: You can start Firefox in safemode by clicking the `Restart with Add-ons disabled` option in the Help Menu.